# How to start service after Clear Data?

Tags: android, service, restart

In my application i'm using a service which monitors the device's movments.
When user clears data, using setting's clear data, the service has been killed by the system.
How can i restart it? i'm using `START_STICKY` in
 `onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)`.

Answer (score 1):

because of  a bug in android 2.3 , when a service is killed and restarted it's onStartCommand will not  be called again. for this..
do everything in the service's onCreate. Only return START_STICKY from onStartCommand.
The problem is just that their 
onStartCommand() is not called with null at that time.  The onCreate() 
method is still called.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was having the same issue in my application and my service was destroyed !. I solve this issue by using a timer ! and a broadcast receiver. each 20 second my receiver detect that if my service is running or not ! and reset the timer again for the next 20 second.